# 404 error for some packages when building docker image

Tags: docker, gitlab, dockerfile, gitlab-ci-runner, cicd

when building docker image for gitlab runner base image getting error as :

```
ERRO[2021-12-29T09:46:32Z] Application execution failed                  PID=6622 error="executing the script on the remote host: executing script on container with IP \"3.x.x.x\": connecting to server: connecting to server \"3.x.x.x:x\" as user \"root\": dial tcp 3.x.x.x:x: connect: connection refused"
ERROR: Job failed (system failure): prepare environment: exit status 2. Check https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/shells/index.html#shell-profile-loading for more information
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM registry.gitlab.com/tmaczukin-test-projects/fargate-driver-debian:latest
RUN apt-get install -y wget && \
    apt-get install -y python3-pip && \
    wget https://releases.hashicorp.com/terraform/0.12.24/terraform_0.12.24_linux_amd64.zip && \
    unzip terraform_0.12.24_linux_amd64.zip
    mv terraform /usr/local/bin && \
    chmod -R 777 /usr/local/bin
```

Comment: Where's the 404 error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming the error mentioned in the title is from the `apt-get install` commands. You should be running an `apt-get update` first to get an updated package list. Otherwise apt will be looking for packages from a stale state (whenever the base image was created). You can also [merge the install commands and include a cleanup of temporary files in the same step to reduce layer size](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/dockerfile_best-practices/#sort-multi-line-arguments).

```
FROM registry.gitlab.com/tmaczukin-test-projects/fargate-driver-debian:latest
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y \
      python3-pip \
      wget && \
    wget https://releases.hashicorp.com/terraform/0.12.24/terraform_0.12.24_linux_amd64.zip && \
    unzip terraform_0.12.24_linux_amd64.zip
    mv terraform /usr/local/bin && \
    chmod -R 777 /usr/local/bin && \
    rm terraform_0.12.24_linux_amd64.zip && \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
```